# Hangman Game with Python

Tags: python, beginner, game

I'm super excited to share my hangman game with you. (haven't added the graphics yet...)

I will be using this program as my final project (for school), but I would like to have this polished before handing it in. I have given my program the limit of 7 attempts, but if the user continues to guess the wrong letters and then suddenly guesses the right letter, the attempt count stays where it's at.

Here's what I mean:

Let's say the word the computer has chosen is 'cougar' (I'm going to pretend I don't actually know this).

BTW this is on my console:

```
Guess the word: ______
7 chances left

a # <-- my input (1st actual input)
Yes! a is in the word!

Guess the word: ____a_
7 chances left

b # <-- my input (2nd actual input)
Sorry, b is not in the word. Try again.

Guess the word: ____a_
6 chances left

b # <-- my input (this was just to test out if my program would let me know that I have repeated a letter)
You already guessed b. Please try another one!

Guess the word: ____a_
6 chances left

t # <-- my input (3rd actual input)
Sorry, t is not in the word. Try again.

Guess the word: ____a_
5 chances left

q # <-- my input (4th actual input)
Sorry, q is not in the word. Try again.

Guess the word: ____a_
4 chances left

r # <-- my input (5th actual input)
Yes! r is in the word!

Guess the word: ____ar
4 chances left

h # <-- my input (6th actual input)
Sorry, h is not in the word. Try again.

Guess the word: ____ar
3 chances left

c # <-- my input (7th actual input)
```

this is where the program should've initially said
'Sorry, you ran out of attempts. The word was cougar. Maybe next time ☹.

instead, I get this:

```
Yes! c is in the word!

Guess the word: c___ar
3 chances left # <-- this is WRONG!!

g # <-- my input (my 1st extra attempt)
Yes! g is in the word!

Guess the word: c__gar
3 chances left

i # <-- my input (my 2nd extra attempt)
Sorry, i is not in the word. Try again.

Guess the word: c__gar
2 chances left

o # <-- my input (my 3rd extra attempt)
Yes! o is in the word!

Guess the word: co_gar
2 chances left

u # <-- my input (my 4th extra attempt)
Yes! u is in the word!

Awesome! You guessed cougar!
```

So my program is supposed to allow only 7 attempts (with the exception of a repeated letter). As you can clearly see I got **12** attempts! Out of which only 8 were acceptable (7 actual attempts and 1 for repeating 'b'), meaning I got 4 EXTRA attempts. (this is what I need to fix).

Here's my code:

```
from random import choice

words = choice(['ant', 'alpaca', 'baboon', 'badger', 'bat', 'bear', 'beaver', 'camel', 'cat', 'clam', 'cobra', 'cougar',
                'coyote', 'crow', 'deer', 'dog', 'donkey', 'duck', 'eagle', 'ferret', 'fox', 'frog', 'goat', 'goose',
                'hawk', 'lion', 'lizard', 'llama', 'mole', 'monkey', 'moose', 'mouse', 'mule', 'newt', 'otter', 'owl',
                'panda', 'parrot', 'pigeon', 'python', 'rabbit', 'ram', 'rat', 'raven', 'rhino', 'salmon', 'seal',
                'shark', 'sheep', 'skunk', 'sloth', 'snake', 'spider', 'stork', 'swan', 'tiger', 'toad', 'trout',
                'turkey', 'turtle', 'weasel', 'whale', 'wolf', 'wombat', 'zebra'])

guessed = []
wrong = []
attempts = 7

while attempts > 0:

    out = ''

    for letter in words:
        if letter in guessed:
            out = out + letter
        else:
            out = out + '_'

    if out == words:
        break

    print('Guess the word:',out)
    print(attempts,'chances left\n')

    guess = input()

    if guess in guessed or guess in wrong:
        print('You already guessed',guess+ '.','Please try another one!')
    elif guess in words:
        print('Yes!',guess,'is in the word!')
        guessed.append(guess)
    else:
        print('Sorry,',guess,'is not in the word. Try again.')
        attempts = attempts - 1
        wrong.append(guess)

    print()

if attempts:
    print('Awesome! You guessed',words + '!')
else:
    print('Sorry you ran out of attempts. The word was',words + '.', 'Maybe next time ☹')
```

Comment: All you need to do to fix your code is add `attempts = attempts - 1` when the person guesses right. But normally when playing hangman correct guesses do not count. Are you sure you want your game to work like that?

Comment: @ThisIsAQuestion I think that would be better as it just leads me to get confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great job on your project!  You're amazing!

I reviewed your code and, rather than fixing the attempts variable, I removed it entirely and used `7-len(wrong)` to get the remaining attempts.  This seems to fix your issue.  Also, I change the if statement at the end to `if len(wrong) != 7` because the other if statement didn't make sense while using `len`.  The way I put it, it will only congratulate you if you have less than 7 attempts used before it calls the `break`.

The hardest part of fixing the code was testing it as I suck at hangman ;).  If you need more help with this project, please let me know!

Here is your code:

```
from random import choice

words = choice(['ant', 'alpaca', 'baboon', 'badger', 'bat', 'bear', 'beaver', 'camel', 'cat', 'clam', 'cobra', 'cougar',
                'coyote', 'crow', 'deer', 'dog', 'donkey', 'duck', 'eagle', 'ferret', 'fox', 'frog', 'goat', 'goose',
                'hawk', 'lion', 'lizard', 'llama', 'mole', 'monkey', 'moose', 'mouse', 'mule', 'newt', 'otter', 'owl',
                'panda', 'parrot', 'pigeon', 'python', 'rabbit', 'ram', 'rat', 'raven', 'rhino', 'salmon', 'seal',
                'shark', 'sheep', 'skunk', 'sloth', 'snake', 'spider', 'stork', 'swan', 'tiger', 'toad', 'trout',
                'turkey', 'turtle', 'weasel', 'whale', 'wolf', 'wombat', 'zebra'])

guessed = []
wrong = []

while len(wrong) < 7:

    out = ''

    for letter in words:
        if letter in guessed:
            out = out + letter
        else:
            out = out + '_'

    if out == words:
        break

    print('Guess the word:',out)
    print(7-len(wrong),'chances left\n')

    guess = input()

    if guess in guessed or guess in wrong:
        print('You already guessed',guess+ '.','Please try another one!')
    elif guess in words:
        print('Yes!',guess,'is in the word!')
        guessed.append(guess)
    else:
        print('Sorry,',guess,'is not in the word. Try again.')
        wrong.append(guess)

    print()

if len(wrong) != 7:
    print('Awesome! You guessed',words + '!')
else:
    print('Sorry you ran out of attempts. The word was',words + '.', 'Maybe next time ☹')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! And @Salocor YOU'RE awesome for taking the time to help me!!

Comment: No problem!  If this solved your problem, it'd be great if you marked my solution as the answer :).

Answer (score 4):

You are improving, that's nice.

Since the project is quite minimal, I would just highlight few points for consideration.

### Misleading variable names

`words` and `out` are misleading, what does `out` mean, your variables should explain themselves clearly and be as unambiguous as possible, `words` gives the intent of holding multiple words but actually, it holds just a word.

### You might not need it

`wrong` list is totally unnecessary here, you might have implemented it for future purposes but right now, it isn't really used, define only what you are currently using. So it means `guess in wrong` is an irrelevant check

`guessed` happens to append only correct guesses, that's misleading, you might want to make it append both correct and wrong guess and it makes the variable `wrong` even more irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for your insight @theProgrammer. I appreciate your feedback and I will make sure to use your suggestions :)